# Angular: How to check validation of child component

Tags: javascript, angular, components

When check validation of child component, Which is better take a reference of child component and call its validate  method or  make an output with Boolean flag and handle it in parent component?

Answer (score 0):

When you add reference to a child, you have following benefits:

1. You have access to all methods in child component.
2. You have access to other variables in the same.
3. You can reset the form after submitting.
4. In case of form control, you can play with validators.

I hope, you will get the answer from above all points.